# how do I sort the list of lists below in groovy

Tags: sorting, collections, groovy

i have a list of lists in groovy like this

```
 udbmslList=[
           [133, 2011-11-30 00:00:00.0], 
           [141, 2011-11-29 00:00:00.0], 
           [132, 2011-11-28 00:00:00.0], 
           [11, 2011-12-03 00:00:00.0], 
           [119, 2011-12-02 00:00:00.0], 
           [182, 2011-12-01 00:00:00.0], 
           [12, 2011-12-04 00:00:00.0]
           ]
```

How do I sort the above list in to a single list/Map or keeping the same structure (list of lists) in ascending order of date (there cannot be 2 same dates in list above)
Also I want to remove the time part of the date.
Thanks

Comment: What are the actual data types? Are those dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the list, assuming those are actually dates, instead of the invalid immediate shown:

```
sorted = udbmslList.sort { it[1] }
```

Use `SimpleDateFormat` or Groovy's `Date` extensions to not remove the time.

To create an array of the same structure but with a date-only string element (using some fake data):

```
s = udbmslList.sort { it[1] }.collect { [it[0], it[1].format('yyyy-MM-dd')] }
=> [[141, 2012-01-26], [133, 2012-01-26], [11, 2012-01-26]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort your list, use `udbmslList.sort { it[1] }`.

To display the dates without a time, you would use something like `udbmslList.each { println it[1].format('yyyy-MM-dd') }`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates are strings, as they seem to be in yyyy-MM-dd format, they can be sorted lexicographically.

```
def udbmslList=[
    [133, "2011-11-30 00:00:00.0"], 
    [141, "2011-11-29 00:00:00.0"], 
    [132, "2011-11-28 00:00:00.0"], 
    [11,  "2011-12-03 00:00:00.0"], 
    [119, "2011-12-02 00:00:00.0"], 
    [182, "2011-12-01 00:00:00.0"], 
    [12,  "2011-12-04 00:00:00.0"]
]

// Get rid of the timestamp part of the date and convert into a map.
def result = udbmslList.collectEntries { 
    [(it[0]): it[1].split()[0]] 
}

// Sort by date lexicographically.
result.sort { it.value }

assert result == [
    132: "2011-11-28", 
    141: "2011-11-29", 
    133: "2011-11-30", 
    182: "2011-12-01", 
    119: "2011-12-02", 
    11: "2011-12-03", 
    12: "2011-12-04"
]
```

**Edit**: If the dates are `Date` objects, then you can first sort the list by date and then transform it into a map with the appropiate format:

```
def result = udbmslList.sort { it[1] }
                       .collectEntries { [(it[0]): it[1].format('yyyy-MM-dd')] }
```

Comment: would be great if you can help me to process this list ...refer to my next question..